# I want serial number continue on all pages

Tags: php, wordpress

This is my code and I am using it as a serial number to show the post with serial number. It's showing 1,2,3,4,5..... and for next page it again start with 1,2,3,4,5....
    But I want to use is to start with 6,7,8,9,10 for next page.

```
<?php 
                wp_reset_query(); 
          if($pub->have_posts()){   

            $p_nos = $paged-1;
            $zod = $item_per_page*$p_nos;
            $i = $count-$zod;
            $i=1;
            while($pub->have_posts()): $pub->the_post();
              $pub_id= get_the_ID(); 
              $content= get_the_content($pub_id);
?>
```

Comment: is this your answer ? https://developer.wordpress.org/reference/functions/wp_get_recent_posts/#source

Answer (score -1, accepted):

```
<?php 
                wp_reset_query(); 
          if($pub->have_posts()){   

            $p_nos = $paged-1;
            $zod = $item_per_page*$p_nos;
            $i = $zod+1;

            while($pub->have_posts()): $pub->the_post();
              $pub_id= get_the_ID(); 
              $content= get_the_content($pub_id);
?>
```

Comment: Please add some explanation to your answer by editing it, such that others can learn from it

Answer (score 0):

You need to sort the results by date in ascending order. Assuming that you are using WP query to display posts.

Use the below code for sorting posts in ascending order. The below code sorts the post using DATE field. If you want, you can even change to other fields like title etc.

```
$args = array(
            'post_type' => 'post',
            'orderby' => 'date',
            'order' => 'ASC',
            'posts_per_page' => 12
        );

        $pub = new WP_Query($args);
```